# Как раскрасить нижную часть картинки в которой добавлен SVG

Tags: css

У меня есть главная страница сайта в котором отражается самопечатающийся текст плюс картинка заднего фона.И вставил туда `SVG` треуголник.

Ну вот внизу после SVG треуголника показывается часть заднего фона  как это убрать может кто в курсе?

```css
.svg-color {
     z-index: 8;
     position: relative;
     border-width: 0;
     border-color: transparent;

     /* more than in bg-image */
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
.browser_width {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
}
#triangle-1 path {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
    fill: #f5f5f5;
    stroke: #f5f5f5;
}
.bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://berlin.aftermotion.com/berlin/images/home-2-u233-fr.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bg-image" style="color:#fff;">
               TEST

                <h1 id="typed-strings" style="color:#fff;">
                    We are
                    <span class="element">Design</span>
                </h1>
                <div class="browser_width" style="height: 154px;">
                    <div class="svg-color">
                        <svg id="triangle-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="0 0 100 150" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                            <path d="M0,5 L30,130 100,5 100,150 0,150Z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарии в коде `HTML`

```css
.svg-color {
  z-index: 8;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  /* more than in bg-image */
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.browser_width {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
}

#triangle-1 path {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
  fill: #f5f5f5;
  stroke: #f5f5f5;
}

.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://berlin.aftermotion.com/berlin/images/home-2-u233-fr.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="bg-image" style="color:#fff;">
      TEST
      <h1 id="typed-strings" style="color:#fff;">
        We are
        <span class="element">Design</span>
      </h1>
      <!-- изменил стороку ниже, надо было поменять высоту блока
                было style="height: 154px;"
                стало style="height: 150px;"
                -->
      <div class="browser_width" style="height: 150px;">
        <div class="svg-color">
          <svg id="triangle-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="0 0 100 150" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M0,5 L30,130 100,5 100,150 0,150Z"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а решение было так легко я даже не обратил внимание.Спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...